# Sharepoint 2010 Views and Conditional Formatting Issue

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, list-view

So I created a task list and using SharePoint Designer I created Conditional Formatting on the default all tasks view and it worked great. However when adding the list in as a web part the conditional formatting is gone, even after specifying the web part to use the all tasks view. I'm still pretty new to SharePoint so I'm hoping it is just a simple view issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the behavior is expected. You have selected "All Tasks" and that brings the data defined in the view to the web part. But formatting is applied by XSLT which it does not get from the view.

Comment: Thanks Ahsish! Any recommendations on how the same XSLT styling can be applied to the web part list?

Comment: Well, once the web part is dropped on the page, you can open the page in SharePoint designer and select the web part and apply the conditional formatting again.